# php mail() function randomly crashing

Tags: php, apache, email

Edit: I created a background process that just sends outgoing mail every minute.  This serializes the sending of email and the mail() function does not seem to be exiting anymore.  However, I would still like to find out why it was crashing in the first place..

The mail() function is randomly exiting/crashing with no error in the Apache log, no Exception being generated, it's not returning a value, the process is just exiting.  Most of the time it does not crash.  I don't see any pattern in the emails that the mail() function is exiting with.  I can't find a reason why it's exiting sometimes.  I tried with and without PHPMailer.

Users schedule appointments on the site.  Each PHP process may send two emails when some actions are taken by the user.   At some times, of course, the site may be more busy than others.

How can I make it so that mail() doesn't randomly crash?

There's nothing spectacular about the mail() call or the emails.

```
mail($recipients, $subject, $txt, $headers, $params);
```

PHP Version 7.3.11
Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)

Details from when sent via PHPMailer (although not using PHPMailer didn't help):

```
subject: =?us-ascii?Q?***Please_Do_Not_Reply***_<redacted person name>_has_take?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?n_exam_Midterm_Exam_for_<course name>?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?065_-_601?=

header:  
Date: Sat, 31 Oct 2020 23:40:39 -0400
From: <from email>
Message-ID: <sqvWfCXXaqzMie8edISkKhWIeHcCBA5S1gVqefBQ@online.northcarolina.edu>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.1.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
Reply-To: <reply to email>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="b1_sqvWfCXXaqzMie8edISkKhWIeHcCBA5S1gVqefBQ"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

additional sendmail params: '-f<an email here>'
```

Comment: Do you check for errors when calling `mail()`?

Comment: What does PHPMailer have to do with this?

Comment: @Barmar I was making the point that it happens with or without PHPMailer. I thought it was PHPMailer, but apparently not.   mail() just crashes/exits.  The process apparently terminates from some reason.  I don't see any errors in the log.

Comment: I didn't know that PHPMailer was used with mail(), I thought it was a completely different API.

Comment: @Barmar  I suppose you could configure PHPMailer to use some other method.

Comment: I've never used it, I just assumed it did everything itself rather than using `mail()`. Similar to the way `curl` does everything itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code to sent a mail with required values

```
<?php
     $to ='To Address';
     $subject = "Subject of the message";
     $message .= "Message of the part";
      
     $header = "From:From Address";
     $header .= "Cc:CC Mail \r\n";
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
     
     $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
     
     if($retval == true ) {
        echo "Mail Sent Successfully...";
     }else {
        echo "Mail Not Sent...";
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: Since he didn't post his code, how do you know that this is different from what he's doing?